# Trying to install youtube-dl but it shows an error

Tags: homebrew, youtube-dl

~ % brew install youtube-dl
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
Error: No available formula or cask with the name "youtube-dl".
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.

Comment: could you please elaborate it a bit?

Answer (score 0):

Try `brew update` first.
If the problem persists, please share the output for `brew doctor`, it shows the problem with solutions.